# How to get data from table by intermediaries

Tags: mysql, join

I have three table:

```
// users
+----+------+------------+
| id | name | reputation |
+----+------+------------+

// posts
+----+-------+---------+
| id | title | user_id |
+----+-------+---------+

// votes
+----+---------+---------+
| id | user_id | post_id |
+----+---------+---------+
```

**Note:** `user_id` in `votes` is belong to who gives a vote. But `user_id` in `posts` table is belong to who wrote that post.

So I want to give +5 rep to the owner of post when his comment get a upvote.

**Example:** when *userA* gives a upvote to the post (wroted by *userB*), I want to run this:

```
update users set reputatuin=reputation+5 where id = {how get the id of userB}
```

Now I want to know, how should I obtain the userB (post owner who wrote it) id ?

Comment: Does the `votes` table also have a `post_id` column to identify the post voted on?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski yes, I edited ! the point is identifying the owner of post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an `UPDATE` statement, you must join through `posts` to the `votes` table using [MySQL's multi-table `UPDATE` syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html).

If you want to update by targeting the `votes.id` of the new vote, use that in the `WHERE` clause.

```
UPDATE 
  users
  INNER JOIN posts ON users.id = posts.user_id
  INNER JOIN votes ON votes.post_id = posts.id
SET
  users.reputation = users.reputation + 5
WHERE votes.id = {vote id to update}
```

If your code is already aware of the `posts.id` of the voted post, then the `votes` table need not be joined and you can use `users` and `posts`.

```
UPDATE 
  users
  INNER JOIN posts ON users.id = posts.user_id
SET
  users.reputation = users.reputation + 5
WHERE posts.id = {post id of new vote}
```

This query can be done just as easily with a subquery in the `WHERE` clause.

```
UPDATE users
SET reputation = reputation + 5
WHERE 
  id = (SELECT user_id FROM posts WHERE post_id = {post id of new vote})
```

Comment: If you have free time, and if it is possible, and please, take a look to my new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32157945/how-to-check-the-number-of-user-reputation-before-storing-his-vote-via-trigger). You are who that always give me exactly what I want ...