# How to check the number of user reputation before storing his vote via trigger

Tags: php, mysql, triggers

I have two tables. `Posts`, `Votes`. I have a column in the `Posts` table named `total_votes`. Also I have a trigger for updating it when user gives a vote to the post.

Here is my trigger:

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER total_votes AFTER INSERT ON Votes
 FOR EACH ROW begin 
   update posts set total_votes = total_votes+new.value
   where  post.id = new.post_id; 
end //
```

So I need to check the number of user reputation, that If they are more than 50, then the vote stores, else, the vote not store. how can I do that ?

Actually I can write this: `BEFORE INSERT`

```
If ((select reputation from users where id = new.user_id) < 50) then
  SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'your rep are low';
end if;
```

Now I have two problem, One: how can I use of that error *(your rep are low)* in my website ? (via php), and two: How can I deactivate `total_votes` trigger (`AFTER INSERT`) if the above condition was `true` ?

Comment: If you are using PDO then checkout the error handler, you should have some functions to get the error message and I believe the same could be done using the mysqli extension too.